# extract the data between two pattern and save it with different name

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file with lots of value in a single file. I need to extract the data in between `name 1` and `name 2`. I need a loop so that I can extract and save data in between using `name1.dat`, `name2.dat` and so on.

My file looks like :

```
name        1
data......
name        2
data.....
```

and so on.

I need to extract data between `name 1` and `name 2`.

I have did

```
for i in 1 2; do awk '$1=="name" and $2=="'$i'"
```

but I am stuck. How can I print in between?

Comment: Hi, In this question i need to save each data to its name. the question is not all the data between the pattern into a single file. i have name 1 to name 200. i will get name1.dat ...name200.dat file.

Comment: Try `awk '/name/{file=$1 $2 ".dat";next}{print > (file)}' file`

Comment: This is not working. I have a file file.dat and it consist of data inside "name  1" is a pattern and end pattern could be before the line of "name  2 ". name is in first column and 1 is on second column. I need the save the data in between name 1 and name 2 as name1.dat and between name 2 and name 3 as name2.dat.